# Saving bool value in Core Data

Tags: uitableview, core-data, boolean

I want to make an alarm app, and I have a uitableview, on wich row I have a switch, on or off, now I want to save in core data what user selected, on or off.... Here is my code where I try to save in Core Data...

```
CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
NSNumber *numberAsBool = [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.switchLabel.on];
self.entry.active = numberAsBool;
[coreDataStack saveContext];
```

But everytime the value is 0. Anyone have an idea??

Comment: How is self.entry defined and populated?

Comment: Dear pbasdf I understand that the way I'm doing is wrong, I need to set in Core Data that the switch is on or off, how to do this, can you tell me please???

Comment: Is this the only bit of data you need to store?  If so, CoreData is probably "a sledgehammer to crack a nut" - use NSUserDefaults instead.  If you are storing more data, please can you edit your post to explain the data structure?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
NSNumber *numberAsBool = [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.switchLabel.on];
```

It should be:

```
NSNumber *numberAsBool = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[self.switchLabel isOn]];
```

Comment: Yes I tried but not working, maybe I update in core data in wrong way. I don't now what could be the problem.